# cURL failing with URLs containing brackets

Tags: curl

cURL requests fail when I pass it URLs containing brackets (for example, in the Wikipedia link below).

```
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `curl -g --silent --max-time 5 --location http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_(disambiguation)'
```

I've been through the manual pages, but I couldn't find anything relevant. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use double quotes:

```
curl -g --silent --max-time 5 --location "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_(disambiguation)"
```